# Javascript slow when Upgrading from .NET 2.0 to .NET 3.5

Tags: javascript, asp.net, performance

I would like to move our solution to .NET 3.5 and VS 2008. We are still on VS 2005 and 2.0. Some tools we would like to use are phasing out 2.0 and 2005 support, so I thought I'd test our solution after upgrading to 3.5.

I converted the project in VS 2008. I fixed some compile errors that popped up, and then fixed up some javascript name change that occured involving the AjaxToolkit.

Everything looked ok, but when I came to a particular page that is quite heavy with validators and javascript...the page slowed to a crawl on loading.

I used the IE 7 javascript profiler, and saw some completely crazy numbers in the .NET javascript methods. I don't know what is going on.

Has anyone run into the problem? Do I having something misconfigured.

I'm including below 2 profiles. One captured when running in .NET 2.0. Another when running on .NET 3.5. At this point, I can't even consider 3.5, if I can not solve this problem.

2.0 Profile

https://spreadsheets.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AvxeS-OgIIkCdERSYVprOTRXZ2lkaFpqMkFFSkkxMXc&hl=en_US&authkey=CKKB5t0I

3.5 Profile

https://spreadsheets.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AvxeS-OgIIkCdGhHdVJRS0FWcEp4azN0SHkxNWF5eUE&hl=en_US&authkey=CNHyu6cG

Please help...this is crazy.

Thanks,
Rich

---Update

Omar, I did as you suggested and set debug=false in the web.config file. This solved the problem. I put timing code in the page's javascript, and the javascript went from taking 17-18 seconds, back down to ~5 seconds. This is around the same time the page takes in .NET 2.0, so I'm satisfied with that (though, would love for IE to run this code faster).

My only problem now is that, I obviously run the solution with debug=true during development. This is a serious hit to my productivity, as this page is used quite frequently. I'm guessing the new javascript debugging abilities introduced in VS 2008 are responsible for all this. When debug=true, I'm guessing a debug build of the .NET javascript libraries are used.

Does anyone have any advice for work-around? Thanks - Rich

Comment: The problem is in the code. try removing parts of the javascript that a seems to be slow in the profiler. then see if  there is any differences. if you isolate what functions are slow u can post them here and we will be glad to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have some script in script blocks that are causing problem. Can you nail down which scripts and show?
You should turn off compilation debug=false in web.config and measure the time. if that's also very slow, we have some problem in your script code. May be you are using some code in ajax libraries that need to be changed. Maybe missing some required field, thus causing too many validation errors.

Comment: Omar, I did as you suggested and that solve the performance issue. I'm still wondering how to fix my issue during development. When debug=true, javascript execution time jumps from 5 seconds to 18 seconds.

Comment: When you turn on debug=true, MS AJAX delivers a completely different set of javascript files that has many validation put on it. Thus it causes the problem. If I have answered your question, could you mark it as answer?